# Apache LDAP Authentication only for some virtualhosts

Tags: apache, centos, virtualhost

I have a webserver running Apache 2.4.6 under CentOS 7 in which I have several web resources. I want to apply LDAP authentication only to some of them, so I am trying to do it by creating a single virtualhost for every resource and configure the LDAP authentication only to the resources I want.

This is my attempt:

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/test1.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Servername server_name
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test1

<Directory "/var/www/html/test1">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

#LDAP
SetHandler php-script
Require all denied
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthUserFile /dev/null
AuthName "ldap_auth"
AuthType Basic
AuthLDAPURL ldap_url
AuthLDAPBindDN ldap_dn
AuthLDAPBindPassword ldap_pass
Require ldap-group ldap_group

</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/test2.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  Servername server_name
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test2

  <Directory "/var/www/html/test2">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the relevant information of my current httpd.conf file:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache

<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www">
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

But it always asks for authentication for both test1 and test2 and for test2 I am not even able to load the content after logged in (test1 loads fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally achieved by using *Alias* directive, so:

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/test1.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Servername server_name
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test1

Alias /test1 /var/www/html/test1
<Directory "/var/www/html/test1">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

#LDAP
SetHandler php-script
Require all denied
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthUserFile /dev/null
AuthName "ldap_auth"
AuthType Basic
AuthLDAPURL ldap_url
AuthLDAPBindDN ldap_dn
AuthLDAPBindPassword ldap_pass
Require ldap-group ldap_group

</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/test2.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Servername server_name
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test2

Alias /test2 /var/www/html/test2
<Directory "/var/www/html/test2">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```